# enviar imágenes desde la vista al controlador mediante ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, post, imagen

buenas, estoy enviando un objeto json a mi controlador mediante $.ajax, pero mi problema es que deseo enviar una imagen dentro del mismo objeto, pero al controlador me llega null el campo probar que es el de la imagen. aqui el codigo:

```
cabePreg = {
                "modelPregunta.ponderacion": ponderacion,
                "modelPregunta.indicaciones": $("#indicaciones").val(),
                "modelDestreza.idDestreza": $("#destre").val(),
                "modelTipoPreg.idTipo": $("#dDLTipoAct").val(),
                "probar": $("#extraIma").val,
                "modelListaRespuesta": listasRes,
                "modelApoyo": extras
            }
$.ajax({
url: "/Docente/ingesarPregutna",
type: 'POST',
data: JSON.stringify({ variosModelos: cabePreg}),
contentType: 'application/json',
processData: false,
success: function (data) {

}
});
```

en el modelo el campo probar esta asi:

```
public HttpPostedFileBase probar { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya pude resolver mi problema, era al momento de obtener la imagen del input file y guardarla en frmData. tenia que hacerlo de esta manera:

```
 var frmData = new FormData();
        frmData.append("modelPregunta.ponderacion", ponderacion);
        frmData.append("modelPregunta.indicaciones", $("#indicaciones").val());
        frmData.append("modelPregunta.idDestreza", $("#destre").val());
        frmData.append("modelPregunta.idTipo", $("#dDLTipoAct").val());
        frmData.append("probar",document.getElementById("inpImag").files[0]);
```

gracias Gustavo García por tus comentarios... me ayudaron muchisimo

Answer (score 0):

> `data: JSON.stringify({ variosModelos: cabePreg}),
>   contentType: 'application/json',`

No puedes hacer eso, es incorrecto. Si quieres enviar imágenes o cualquier tipo de archivo, debes hacerlo de forma binaria ya que eso son. Para esto puedes usar `FormData`:

```
let data = new FormData(form);
```

Donde `form` es el nodo formulario. Una vez hecho esto, puedes enviar toda la información del formulario contenido en dicho objeto; también puedes agregar y eliminar valores dinámicamente por medio de los métodos `FormData#append` y `FormData#remove`:

> **Nota:** Ten en cuenta que `FormData` serializará tu formulario usando el atributo `name` de cada control como clave. Así que asegúrate de ponerlos.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/Docente/ingesarPregutna",
  type: 'POST',
  data: data
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  success: function (data) {
    // hacer algo
  }
});
```

Es importante que establezcas la opción `contentType` a `false` de lo contrario jQuery intentará parsear el FormData para enviarlo como texto.

En el backend, los archivos binarios estarán disponibles por medio de `Request#Files` en tu controlador. Para obtener la imagen basta pasar el nombre que has asociado a ella en el FormData; por ejemplo:

```
Request.Files["avatar"];
```

Comment: hola, lo que sucede es que estoy haciendo un sistema dinamico, por lo que la información la recibo de diferentes form. ademas existen ciertos valores como listasRes que son obtenidos mediante un metodo JS. por eso es que no puedo enviar directamente el form

Comment: **No estás enviando un form**, si no un objeto `FormData`. Un objeto `FormData` puede agregar valores de manera dinámica por medio de `append` y puede removerlas por medio de `remove`. No importa si tienes 20 formularios, tu puedes seleccionar qué valores enviar en un solo `FormData`, incluyendo imágenes o archivos varios.

Comment: amigo , lo hice asi: 
var frmData = new FormData();
            frmData.append("modelPregunta.ponderacion", ponderacion);
            frmData.append("modelPregunta.idDestreza", $("#destre").val());
            frmData.append("modelPregunta.idTipo", $("#dDLTipoAct").val());
            frmData.append("probar", ("#extraIma").val);
            frmData.append("modelListaRespuesta", listasRes);
 y en el controlador lo recivo asi:
public ActionResult ingesarPregutna(VariosModel frmData){}
pero todos los campos me llegan nulos. que hago mal?

Comment: Hola @BryanG., Al parecer no te está llegando la petición. Inspecciona la web, y dirígete hacia la pestaña Red. Allí verás que salen todas las peticiones que hagas, filtra por AJAX (`xhr`) y dale click en tu petición. Mira qué respuesta te devuelve.

Comment: le puse contentType: false, y ya me llegan los campos al controlador, menos el de la imagen

Comment: Los archivos que se suben están disponibles en `Request.Files` en .NET. Por ejemplo, si has mandado la imagen en el FormData con el nombre `avatar` entonces recuperas el archivo así: `Request.Files["avatar"]`.